# In-App Notifications?

Tags: iphone, xcode, notifications, in-app

I'm trying to create functionality in my app that would allow me to release news updates (Via a server) to those using the app, similar to what is found in Doodle Jump:
http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7143/6463110847_d485681dac.jpg

Any sample code or ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably need to create an API/web service that your app calls on launch (or when entering foreground)...you could populate that with a database that just gives the entries since the last sync...or just returns some response that you've set up. The response should be JSON or XML formatted (I vote JSON) and then in your app, you call it, parse the response, and place/manipulate it however necessary

http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/

Comment: Do you know any tutorials that outline this? I'm not very familiar with this area. Edit: Thanks, I'll try it out.

Comment: added one...you can google: nsurlconnection example json for other options

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of options here. In any case you will need a web server that hosts these news postings. The route that I would take is some kind of blog site, where you can easily manage posts. Then upon launching the app you make a web service call to said blog and get the news posts. You will need to keep track locally of which posts were read by the user in order to keep the badge count correct.

You could also roll your own server, but I don't really see the point for something so simple.

Another option is a web-service such as [Parse](https://www.parse.com/)

This question is too vague for code samples as we would be essentially writing the entire solution for you in order for it to make sense.

If you have further questions into how to leverage these web services, how to load the feed, how to display it etc... Break it up across multiple questions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be looking more into Parse, as I have very little experience with Server-related functionality.

Comment: They have some excellent tutorials on how to use their service so I think it will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

There's a service doing this called [Converser](http://converser.io), if you're still looking.